# CSS for select option doesn't work on chrome

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to get color options in the select option. This code works fine in mozilla, however it doesn't seem to work on chrome:

```
<style>
.color_box option:after {
content: " ";
height: 15px;
width: 65px;
display: inline-block;
}
option.black:after { background: #000000; }
option.red:after { background: #CB0F0F; }
option.purple:after { background: #8B11AA; }
</style>

<select class="color_box">
<option>Select</option>
<option class="black" value="#000000"></option>
<option class="red" value="#CB0F0F"></option>
<option class="purple" value="#8B11AA"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddel

Answer (score 0):

Just css seems not work well.

Do you want to let it work like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kvxsjyv0/1/

```
<style>
        option.black { background: #000000; color:#000000 }
        option.red { background: #CB0F0F; color: #CB0F0F; }
        option.purple { background: #8B11AA;color: #8B11AA; }
        option.default {background: #fff;}

    </style>
    <select class="color_box" onchange="this.style.background = this.value!=''?this.value:'#fff'">
        <option class="default" value="">Select</option>
        <option class="black" value="#000000"></option>
        <option class="red" value="#CB0F0F"></option>
        <option class="purple" value="#8B11AA"></option>
    </select>
```